# ALM Excel macro for test-lab extractor folder wise

Tags: sql, excel, vba, alm

I am looking to develop a excel macro which will be able to fetch data from ALM test-lab folder wise. I need the data in the following format  :

- Test Set Folder Name,
- Test Set Name,
- Test Case Name,
- Test Case Status,
- Tester Name,
- Test Step Execution Date

I am new to SQL so any help to build the SQL will be very much helpful.
Also want the folder path for data extraction to be specified by the user and to use the path in the SQL query.

Answer (score 0):

I used the following format but the report generated is in a different format:

SELECT CF_ITEM_NAME as 'Test Set Folder Name',CY_CYCLE as 'Test Set Name',TS_NAME as 'Test Case Name',RN_STATUS as 'Test Case Status',ST_STEP_NAME as 'Test Step Name',ST_STATUS as 'Test Step Status',ST_DESCRIPTION as 'Test Step Description',ST_EXPECTED as 'Test Step Expected Result',ST_ACTUAL as 'Test Step Actual Result',RN_HOST as 'Test Host Name',RN_TESTER_NAME as 'Tester Name',ST_EXECUTION_DATE as 'Test Step Execution Date',ST_EXECUTION_TIME as 'Test Step Execution Time' FROM STEP a, TEST b, CYCLE c,RUN d,CYCL_FOLD e where a.ST_TEST_ID=b.TS_TEST_ID and c.CY_CYCLE_ID=d.RN_CYCLE_ID and d.RN_TEST_ID=b.TS_TEST_ID and e.CF_ITEM_ID=c.CY_FOLDER_ID and RN_HOST IS NOT NULL and RN_TESTER_NAME IS NOT NULL and CF_ITEM_PATH like 'AAAAAAAAD%' ORDER BY TS_NAME,RN_RUN_ID,ST_RUN_ID,ST_EXECUTION_DATE,ST_EXECUTION_TIME ASC